# Errors with onSubmit handler if submit is called via this.props.submit('formname')

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am having an Error with onSubmit handler in Redux-Form when called from the action creator provided by redux-form. If I use a regular button inside it works as it should.

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Property extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.saveOnChange = this.saveOnChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        console.log('form submitting');
    }

    saveOnChange() {
        console.log('should auto save');
        this.props.dispatch(this.props.submit('propertySettings'));
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
                // Stuff goes here

                <div onClick={this.saveOnChange}>(just for example it is with a div)</div> // <-- Get's errors
                <button type='submit'>Via button</button> // <-- Work's fine
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

**Received errros when calling via the action creator**

[image]

Comment: What about changing the line to                                                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit.bind(this))}>

Comment: @therewillbecode see updated answer, this error only exists when calling submit with the action creator provided by redux-form

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you were trying to bind the local method of `handleSubmit` to the scope of the component and then pass it as an argument to the `handleSubmit` method on props.

If you are just trying to assign the handleSubmit method to the onSubmit of your form you can try this:

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Property extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    // bind handleSubmit in the constructor, it's more efficient
    // as it only occurs once per lifetime of a component
  }
  handleSubmit() {
    console.log('form submitting');
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit= { this.handleSubmit }> // call it here like this
      // Stuff goes here
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've found that it is only when you are using an action creator to call the submit. See updated question

Comment: You're still assigning handle Submit differently to the way I have suggested.

Comment: Yes but only because the handleSubmit is a prop by redux-form which is needed to handle submit. See my answer as it resolved my issue :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Updating from version redux-form 6.3.x to 6.4.x solved the issue. See [release notes](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.4.0).